# Displaying the Month and Year that a page was Created?

Tags: php, functions, date-time

## Question

How can I display only the Month and Year that a page was created?

## Background

I have a page that will get changes has a field that shows the month and year. It needs to be in Month and year format like "December 2013"

### Code

I previously had this in my template, to display (for example) **December 2013:**

```
<time><?php the_time('F Y') ?>:</time>
```

But since it will only show up on a specific page I wrote this

```
<?php 
    if ( is_page('about/mission-statement/')) {
        $post_month_year = get_post_time(get_option('date_format'), false, $post, true);
        echo '<time>' . $post_month_year . ':' . '</time>';
    }
?>
```

But that gives me the date with the day in addition, **December 12, 2013**.

So the problem is that variable. I thought I could just do something like

```
$post_month_year = 'the_time('F Y’)';
```

I just need the month and year. What did I do wrong and how can I best address this?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I created variables for both the month of the post and the year of the post.

```
<?php
    $post_month  = get_the_time('F');
    $post_year = get_the_time('Y'); 
    if ( is_page('about/mission-statement/')) {
        echo '<time>' . $post_month . ' ' . $post_year . ':' . '</time>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You could simplify it: `$post_date = get_the_time( 'F Y' );` will get the date in `Month Year` format. Then you could simply `echo "<time>$post_date:</time>";` later in your code.